# Errors were encountered while processing: spoofer-gui

Tags: dpkg

[image: Error images]

Please refer to the picture above

Comment: Please don't post images of text: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: did you try installing the requested packages?

Comment: I do not know what it is.

Comment: it says in the error .. you need spoofer-scheduler, libqt5gui5, libqt5gui5-gles, libqt5network5 and libqt5widgets5

Comment: oops ..sorry the spoofer-scheduler is trying to be installed you don't need that one .. seems you just need the libqt files I listed above .. install those and you should be able to install spoofer-gui after those are installed

Comment: You can try to install your application with Gdebi (`sudo gdebi spoofer-*.deb`), it will respect dependencies.

Comment: Please don't post image of text, please post the text. It is important so the question is well indexed, so other users having the same problem can find your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5 libqt5gui5-gles libqt5network5 libqt5widgets5` once those are fully installed you can try installing spoofer-gui again with the command you used

If you receive any errors while installing the above .. copy the text and [EDIT](https://askubuntu.com/posts/986505/edit) your question and paste the error text in you question so we can further troubleshoot the problem